# Is there a way to track the number of times a post has been viewed then display the number in keystonejs

Tags: javascript, keystonejs

I am relatively new to keystone, I want to track the number of times a post has been viewed then display the number of times it has been viewed on each post.
So far I have been able to add a new column to the admin page, but I'm thinking of the best possible way to implement the page view count.

update: this is what I have tried so far. I am trying to get the pageView column and then increment it with MongoDB

```
view.on('init', function (next) {
...
        q.exec(function (err, result) {
            locals.data.post = result;
            keystone.list('Post').model.update({
                $inc: { pageView: 2 }
            })
            console.log(locals.data.post.pageView)
            next(err);
        });
    });
```

```
Post.add({
...
    pageView: { type: Types.Number, default: 0 }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have updated my post to reflect that